# error when installing ssh on beanstalk 64bit ubuntu 2014.03 v1.0.2 PHP 5.5

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed this tutorial (http://richardhawthorn.com/?p=82) to configure ssl on my beanstalk instances.

So my config file contains the following. It works great on **64bit ubuntu 2014.02 PHP 5.5** but on **64bit ubuntu 2014.03 v1.0.2 PHP 5.5** it does not work I get the following errors, what could be the problem?

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod24_ssl : []

Resources:
  mySecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupName: {Ref : AWSEBSecurityGroup}
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: 000777
    owner: ec2-user
    group: ec2-user
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      
        
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateChainFile "/tmp/gd_bundle.crt"
        SSLCertificateFile "/tmp/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/tmp/server.key"

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
        ProxyPreserveHost on

        LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
        TransferLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
```

```
Jun  4 06:12:16 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd main process ended, respawning
Jun  4 06:12:17 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd main process ended, respawning
Jun  4 06:12:17 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd main process ended, respawning
Jun  4 06:12:17 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd main process ended, respawning
Jun  4 06:12:17 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd main process ended, respawning
Jun  4 06:12:17 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd main process ended, respawning
Jun  4 06:12:17 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd main process ended, respawning
Jun  4 06:12:17 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd main process ended, respawning
Jun  4 06:12:18 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd main process ended, respawning
Jun  4 06:12:18 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd main process ended, respawning
Jun  4 06:12:18 ip-10-253-103-13 init: httpd respawning too fast, stopped


-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Wed Jun 04 06:12:18.328490 2014] [suexec:notice] [pid 25739] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess (not sure though) is this issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=545736

Also discussed here:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=546965

Can you try downgrading the version of curl using an ebextension and see if it fixes your problem?